# What does `render` do in unit test below?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Can the code below work without `render(tree, answer)`? What does it do under the hood?

```
   // unit tests
    // do not modify the below code
    describe('tests', function() {
      const answer = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K' ];

  const tree = {
    value: "A",
    left: {
      value: "B",
      left: {
        value: "D",
        left: {
          value: "G",
          left: null,
          right: null
        },
        right: null
      },
      right: {
        value: "E",
        left: null,
        right: {
          value: "H",
          left: {
            value: "K",
            left: null,
            right: null
          }
        }
      }
    },
    right: {
      value: "C",
      left: {
        value: "F",
        left: {
          value: "I",
          left: null,
          right: null
        },
        right: {
          value: "J",
          left: null,
          right: null
        }
      },
      right: null
    }
  };

  render(tree, answer);

  it('breadthFirstTraverse', () => {
    expect(breadthFirstTraverse([tree], [])).toEqual(answer);
    expect(breadthFirstTraverse2([tree], [])).toEqual(answer);
  });
});
```

Comment: Not a method of jasmine library. Only it's author knows what it does!

Comment: Might want to include the code of `render`?